# Statistical significance for high values of IV

Tags: statistical-significance, conditional

I (beginner…) need some general guidance on regression analysis:

I have run an OLS regression on some data and I’ve had some statistically significant relationships between IVs and the DV. My professor now asked me to „make sure that the relationship is not only there for high values in the IV“.

If I understand right, he wants me to make sure that the measured effect holds across the entire range of the IV. In other words, that the effect is not conditional on a specific level of IV.

Is the best way to divide the IV into "high", "middle", and "low" values and run individual regressions for these three (artificial) categories?

Do you have any tips / keywords to look up in that context on what to do specifically?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to ask your professor what he wants.

I can think of two things I might do (assuming no guidance is available). First, I would simply make scatter plots and look. If something more formal is needed, then,  I would try using a spline of the independent variable and see if there are sharp changes in the relationship.  Since he hasn't specified what "high" means, nor has he said that it should be "high", "medium", and "low" (vs. say, "high" and "not high") I think a spline matches the ambiguity with flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

While it is absolutely possible for the relationship to change over the range of the IV. Though the simple way to test for this is to plot the DV and the IV using a scatterplot. If the plot's general shape changes direction drastically over the range of the IV, then there is a non-linear relationship between the IV and the DV (which is what is signified by the relationship between the IV and the DV changing over the range of the IV). You can also simply look at the raw data and determine if there is any change in the rate of change (i.e., does the DV value change by roughly the same amount for each unit increase in IV).

With that being said, I would still confirm with your instructor what exactly they are asking for. But to me it sounds like they are asking if the relationship between the IV and DV is linear or non-linear.

Note: The above answer only applies to simple linear regression. if you are asking about multiple regression, that is a bit more complicated as it requires plotting residual values against predicted values or against the values of individual IVs and testing for other things that I won't get into here unless you are actually asking about multiple regression.